# Delete out of range nodes from linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

The purpose of the code is to delete the nodes that are not in the range I gave (Min and Max) from the linked list I received.
Now, at the current values ​​I entered for the height, the code works, but if you change the height of f1 node to 80 (out of range), you will see that the code will not work (will be incorrect).

I know it's something in the delete (in the method itself) that does not work, I would be happy to get help.

This is my code:

Node:

```
public class Node<T> 
{
    private T value;
    private Node<T> next;
    
    //constructors  
    public Node(T value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public Node(T value, Node<T> next) 
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    //getters setters
    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (this.getNext()!=null);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [value=" + this.value + ", next=" + this.next + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Flower:

```
public class Flower {
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private String color;
    private String season;
    
    public Flower(String name, double height, String color, String season)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        this.season = season;
    }
    
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSeason() {
        return season;
    }

    public void setSeason(String season) {
        this.season = season;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name + "[" + this.height + " cm, " + color + ", " + season+"]";
    }
}
```

FlowerMain (where is the error):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlowerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<Flower> f1 = new Node<Flower>(new Flower("MoranA", 56.46,"Red", "Summer"));
        Node<Flower> f2 = new Node<Flower>(new Flower("MoranB", 55.46,"Red", "Winter"),f1);
        Node<Flower> f3 = new Node<Flower>(new Flower("MoranC", -57.46,"Blue", "Summer"),f2);
        Node<Flower> f4 = new Node<Flower>(new Flower("MoranD", 554.46,"Redd", "Winter"),f3);
        Node<Flower> f5 = new Node<Flower>(new Flower("MoranE", 6747.36,"Red", "Summerr"),f4);
        removeFlowersRange(f5,45,60);
    }
    
    //exc 3
    public static void removeFlowersRange(Node<Flower> flowers, double min, double max)
    {
        
        Node<Flower> current = flowers, prev = null;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(flowers);
        while(current!= null)
        {
            if(current.getValue().getHeight()<min || current.getValue().getHeight()>max)
            {
                prev = flowers;
                flowers = flowers.getNext();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(flowers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function removeFlowersRange is not using the prev variable. Either debug line by line or print the current and flowers variable,so that you know what is going on in the loop, it isn't removing node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never calling the `setNext(Node<T> next)` method in your `removeFlowersRange` method so the linked list never changes.

When the if condition is true, you probably want to remove the node, while making sure that it works when removing from the start of the list and when removing from other positions.

```
public static Node<Flower> removeFlowersRange(Node<Flower> flowers, double min, double max)
{
    Node<Flower> current = flowers, prev = null;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(flowers);
    while(current != null)
    {
        if(current.getValue().getHeight()<min || current.getValue().getHeight()>max)
        {
            // move to the next item
            current = current.getNext();
            if (prev == null) {
                // if we have to remove an item at the start of the list,
                // just move the head of the list, that will drop the first item
                flowers = current;
            } else {
                // otherwise, drop the current item by updating
                // the previous item's next reference
                prev.setNext(current);
            }
        }
        else {
            // if the current item should not be removed
            // just move to the next item normally 
            // (not modifying the linked list)
            prev = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(flowers);

    // since when the item(s) at the start of the list are removed
    // the head of the list changes, we have to return it from this
    // method call if we want to use the changed list anywhere else
    return flowers;
}
```